# Legend text missing when compiling with eps figure

Tags: eps, legend, missing

[image: This is the original figure]

[image: This is the figure shown in pdf]

The upper is the original figure(eps format), the lower is the figure shown in pdf. I don't know why. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance. The tex file is below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{sinewave}
    \centering
    \caption{sine wave}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: it is not related to the problem but you should not load `epsfig` or `epstopdf` you just need `graphicx` here. The issue is probably specific to the way the text is encoded in the EPS file, can you make the EPS file available somewhere so people can debug?

Comment: `[H]`  gives an error in the above (needs float package) but is unrelated to the issue so it would be best to delete that from the example.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your suggestions. First, either `epsfig` or `epstopdf` could be removed. Each error is `File sinewave not found. \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{sinewave}`. Second, `[H]` does not ocurr error on my machine. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bkx1xx1rKgDBT68uN6eUtOvbJN3vb5bW/view?usp=sharing) is the original file. NB: My env is windows 10 and texstudio.

Comment: [H] will give an error on your machine if you do as you ask others to do and copy the document that you have added to your question. It may not give an error in your original docuemnt but that isn't the point. You should delete epsfig, epstopdf and [H] from the example., but the actual issue will be an issue with your eps file, can you make that available somewhere?

Comment: Yes. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bkx1xx1rKgDBT68uN6eUtOvbJN3vb5bW/view) is the original eps file.

Comment: With an up to date texlive 2020 it works as expected and I see the text in the included file. It may be an issue with the ghostscript you have, try including `\includegraphics{sinewave.pdf}` where sinewave.pdf is the pdf I made with epstopdf here https://www.dropbox.com/s/eq2bosyfgq3u9g0/sinewave.pdf?dl=1

Comment: It works! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The posted example works and works in the OPs site with a converted EPS file, which implies that there is an issue with the conversion to PDF. So this is a ghostscript rather than tex issue.

Check that the ghostscript that came with your miktex installation is up to date or use a different online convertor, or different installation of ghostscript, to convert the EPS to PDF.

(There is currently a link to a working converted PDF in comments under the question, but I do not guarantee that link remains good, it is a temporary dropbox share)